# How to execute expressions in moq Repository?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, repository

I have IGeneric repository having function declaration

`T FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);`

and in Generic Repository Class

```
public T FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbset.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }
```

and having the unit Test class, 
create a mock repository and initialize the data in to the mock database

```
[TestClass]
public class ServiceTest
{
    private IClientRepository mockClientRepository;
public ServiceTest()
    {
        IList<ClientData> client = new List<ClientData>
            {
                new ClientData{ Name= "Mike", Address ="Uk" },
                new ClientData{ Name= "Jane", Address ="US" },
            };
         Mock<IClientRepository> _mockRepository = new Mock<IClientRepository>();
        _mockRepository.Setup(m => m.FindBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<ClientData, bool>>>())).Returns((string apiClient) =>
        {
            var data = client.Where(x => x.Hash == apiClient).FirstOrDefault();
            return data;
        });
this.mockClientRepository = _mockRepository.Object;
} 
[TestMethod]
public void IsDataFindByName()
    {
        ClientData testResult = this.mockClientRepository.FindBy(i => i.Name== "Mike");
        Assert.IsNotNull(testResult);
    }
```

i found an exception when i run the test

```
Additional information: Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Adminportal.Entities.ClientData ,System.Boolean]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'.
```

I dont know how to pass it,

Comment: As a sidenote: is this your full test code? In the code provided you are faking an implementation of IClientRepository.FindBy and testing that fake implementation, effectively testing the test code. Given as it is displayed here, this test tests not a single line of production code and provides zero value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameterful `Returns` method expect its parameter to be of same type as mocked method's parameter. You use `.Returns((string apiClient)` when `Expression<Func<ClientData, bool>>` is expected. Simply change it to:

```
.Returns((Expression<Func<ClientData, bool>> expression) =>
{
    var data = client.Where(expression.Compile()).FirstOrDefault();
    return data;
});
```